# Areas not working in my MVC 3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax, asp.net-mvc-areas

Today I found a weird thing in my MVC 3 app. It's quite large so I decided to use Areas. Evrything is setted proper, but for the request on SomeArea/SomeController/SomeAction I recieve 404.

On fresh MVC3 app this works as expected.

I tried to debug the app and I beieve the problem Is in Global.asax in which Method Application_Start calls AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas and this method should fire RegisterArea in TestAreaRegistration class. In RegisterArea is the routing rule for this area.

I fresh app, when I set a brekpoint inside RegisterArea it is reached when server strats, but in previous app, breakpoint on this place in never reached.

I havent found any differences between these two app. Normally I would take the content from previous app and put it into new, but the app is under TFS.

Answer (score 0):

A few things worth checking are:

- Areas are being registered. There should be a MyAreaRegistration.cs file in the area sub folder plus the list in Global.asax.cs
- Does the folder containing the views match the controller name?
- Is your link/ActionLink pointing to the correct place?
- Does your controller have the correct namespace?